# Prove there exists $A \in M_n{(\mathbb R)}$ s.t. $A^2 = \begin{pmatrix} M & 0 \\ 0 & M \\ \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that for all $M \in M_n{(\mathbb R)}$, there exists $A \in M_{2n}{(\mathbb R)}$ s.t. $A^2$ = $$\begin{pmatrix}     M & 0 \\     0 & M \\     \end{pmatrix} $$

I have tried by induction on $n$ but I don't see how to pass from $n$ to $n+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly different hint: $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}^2=I.$

Comment: @rogerl How does this not provide an answer to the question? It is most definitely a hint which leads toward the exact same solution as my answer does, and it certainly doesn't critique or request clarification (yes, I know that's an automatic comment). Hints are explicitly allowed and sometimes even preferred to full answers on this site. Now, it is true that hints are usually given in the comment section, and they might be quite brief, but I am quite certain that if we are to pick nits here, a hint in answer post suits the formal guidelines here better than a hint in comments.

Comment: I realize that the auto comments are kind of restricted. What I really wanted to say was that this should have been a comment, not an answer. I did not downvote it, and nobody else is required to vote to close if they disagree. I may have a different view on these things than others, but I prefer answers to actually be answers. Yes, I'm sure you can find examples where I have done the same thing, but usually with a lot more detail than here.

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable hint. There is no requirement that answers be complete.

Comment: I spent some time on Meta, and I guess that's the consensus. I'll change my own practices going forward as well. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier to do a concrete construction rather than induction. Try to find $A$ in block matrix form, i.e. similar to how you've written $A^2$.

For a further hint:

> Have zero on the block diagonal.